# Django hosting on a domain

Tags: django, web, dns, hosting, project

So far, the only websites I've put in a hosted domain were with PHP. But since I work with Django I wonder if there would be any "barrier" or trouble when it comes about hosting a project, since Linux and IOS have Python installed by default but Windows not. Also it would be necessary to install tools such as Django itself, pillow, mysqlclient, etc...

I just want to know any possible barrier before going ahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on the server, if you have the necessary permissions to install and configure everything, you will not have any problem. How can be gunicorn, supervisor, nginx, etc.
For example services that you will not have any problem can be Amazon EC2, digitalocean, or any similar provider.

Answer (score 1):

When I started with Django about 4 years ago I didn't know anything about servers, nginx and very little about databases but I found [Djangoeurope](https://djangoeurope.com/) on which I put my first websites.

They have managed databases (PostgreSQL and MySQL), one-click Django installs, reasonable prices and a very helpful staff.

I've since transitioned to using Docker on GCP, but for a beginner I can't recommend them enough: you can just concentrate on your Django code and you don't have to learn everything else at the same time.